# Kotlin Gson Deserializing

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I am receiving a JSON data model that has a map wrapper *Table*. I'm trying to use generics to pass in the type that is beyond the wrapper but it's not translating well at runtime. Here's an example of my JSON file:

```
{
"Table": [
 {
   "paymentmethod_id": 1,
   "paymentmethod_description": "Cash",
   "paymentmethod_code": "Cash",
   "paymentmethod_is_ach_onfile": false,
   "paymentmethod_is_element": false,
   "paymentmethod_is_reward": false,
   "paymentmethod_is_openedgeswipe": false,
   "paymentmethod_update_user_id": 1,
   "paymentmethod_insert_user_id": 1,
   "paymentmethod_insertdate": "2014-10-07 14:53:16",
   "paymentmethod_deleted": false,
   "paymentmethod_is_mobile_visible": true
   }
  ]
}
```

The wrapper class I'm using is called Table.

```
data class Table<T>(
    @SerializedName("Table") val models : Array<T>
)
```

The actual model class is PaymentMethod.

```
data class PaymentMethod(
    @SerializedName("paymentmethod_id") val idNumber : Int = -1
)
```

I have created a generic data manager class that takes < T > type. I think use subclasses of the data manager to localize the input and results (such as declaring the model class *PaymentMethod*.

```
open class NXDataManager<T>(manager: NXNetworkManager? = null, rpc : String?, parameters: List<Pair<String, String>>? = null, method : String = "get")
{
   ...


open fun sendRequest(completionHandler: (models:Array<T>) -> Unit, errorHandler: (error:FuelError) -> Unit) {

    val request = NXNetworkRequest(rpc, parameters, method)

    request.send(manager, completionHandler = { s: String ->

        val table: Table<T> = Gson().fromJson(s)

        completionHandler(table.models)

    }, errorHandler = errorHandler)
}

inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String) = this.fromJson<T>(json, object: TypeToken<T>() {}.type)

}
```

My subclassed data manager specifies the model to parse into.

```
final public class PaymentMethodsDataManager : NXDataManager<PaymentMethod>
{
   constructor () : super("genGetPaymentMethods")

}
```

When I run the code as:

```
val table: Table<T> = Gson().fromJson(s)
```

I get an error message **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to Networking.PaymentMethod[]**. However, when I pass in an explicit type it works as expected--parsing the array into PaymentMethod models:

```
val table: Table<PaymentMethod> = Gson().fromJson(s)
```

Any ideas of how I can still use the generic type T?

Answer (score 12):

Data Class :

```
data class Table<T>(
    @SerializedName("Table") val models : Array<T>
)
```

to JSON:

```
val gson = Gson()
val json = gson.toJson(table)
```

from JSON:

```
val json = getJson()
val table = gson.fromJson(json, Table::class.java)
```

Comment: I was not able to use Table::class.java, because Table needs to specify its generic type Table<T>::class.java. But that throws an error because I'm guessing the compiler can't tell what T is at compile time (isn't that kind of the point of generics in the first place?).

Answer (score 4):

Method [`fromJson`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) is generic, so when you call it for `Table<T>` variable it creates `Array<Any>` as most suitable. You need to notice that `PaymentMethod` class extends `T` generic, but I don't know is it even possible. If you find out how to make it, use something like following:

```
val table: Table<T> = Gson().fromJson<Table<PaymentMethod>>(s)
```

In your case I'm using gson adapters. Following function creates object with specified `type` parameter:

```
fun getObjectFromString(type: Type, string: String) =
    Gson().getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type)).fromJson(string)
```

To use it write something following:

```
val table: Table<T> = getObjectFromString(Table<PaymentMethod>::class.java, s) as Table<PaymentMethod>
```

**Update**

To avoid spare class cast you can use `reified` generic function:

```
inline fun <reified T> getObjectFromString(string: String): T =
            getGsonConverter().getAdapter(TypeToken.get(T::class.java)).fromJson(string)!!
```

In that case using would be easier:

```
val table: Table<T> = getObjectFromString<Table<PaymentMethod>>(s)
```

I used first solution in cases where I don't know what type the object would be - I've got only `Type` variable with information about that object.

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to
>   Networking.PaymentMethod[]

Your JSON is

```
{
"Table": [
 {
   "paymentmethod_id": 1,
   "paymentmethod_description": "Cash",
   "paymentmethod_code": "Cash",
   "paymentmethod_is_ach_onfile": false,
   "paymentmethod_is_element": false,
   "paymentmethod_is_reward": false,
   "paymentmethod_is_openedgeswipe": false,
   "paymentmethod_update_user_id": 1,
   "paymentmethod_insert_user_id": 1,
   "paymentmethod_insertdate": "2014-10-07 14:53:16",
   "paymentmethod_deleted": false,
   "paymentmethod_is_mobile_visible": true
   }
  ]
}
```

Create a [**`data class`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), **`PaymentMethod`**.

> We frequently create classes whose main purpose is to hold data. In
>   such a class some standard functionality and utility functions are
>   often mechanically derivable from the data.

```
data class PaymentMethod(@SerializedName("Table") val table:ArrayList<PaymentData> )
data class PaymentData

                      (
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_id") val paymentmethod_id: Int,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_description") val paymentmethod_description: String,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_code") val paymentmethod_code:String,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_is_ach_onfile") val paidStatus:Boolean,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_is_element") val paymentmethod_is_element:Boolean,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_is_reward") val paymentmethod_is_reward:Boolean,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_is_openedgeswipe") val paymentmethod_is_openedgeswipe:Boolean,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_update_user_id") val paymentmethod_update_user_id:Int,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_insert_user_id") val paymentmethod_insert_user_id:Int,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_insertdate") val paymentmethod_insertdate:String,
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_deleted") val paymentmethod_deleted:Boolean),
                       @SerializedName("paymentmethod_is_mobile_visible") val paymentmethod_is_mobile_visible:Boolean
                       )
```

You can call this way

```
  val paymentDATA = Gson().fromJson<PaymentMethod>("JSON_RESPONSE", PaymentMethod::class.java)
  val _adapterPaymentHistory = paymentDATA.table
```