# how to force to get cached documents in Firestore ? I want to get cached documents when online

Tags: android, firebase, caching, google-cloud-firestore

so I have this method to query documents from Firestore:

```
FirestoreCollectionReference.event.getReference()
            .whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_CITY,selectedCity)
            .whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_HAS_BEEN_APPROVED,true)
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME,now.toDate())
            .whereLessThanOrEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME,oneMonthFromNow.toDate())
            .orderBy(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .orderBy(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_RANKPOINT, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(limit)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->

                val eventDocuments = snapshot.documents
                val eventArray = ArrayList<Event>()

                for (document in eventDocuments) {
                    val eventData = document.data
                    val event = Event(dataEvent = eventData)
                    eventArray.add(event)
                }

                completion(null,eventArray)

            }.addOnFailureListener {
                completion(it.localizedMessage,null)
            }
```

I understand that firestore will automatically using the cached documents if my app is offline using that method.

but what I want is ....

let say my app will ALWAYS be online. but I don't want everytime I open the app, it will always fetching data from server. I want to give limitation.

if the last timestamp user fetching data from server is more than one hour ago, then ok, fetching data from server and show up the loading indicator. otherwise just fetch data from cached documents that previously fetched from server and don't show loading indicator.

can I do that ? how to force to get cached documents in Firestore ?I want to get cached documents even when the user is online

I have tried to read the documentation from here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline
but it seems the cached documents can only be retrieved only if the offline case happened. and the example is for realtime listener. in my case, I only use `get()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to explicitly control where `get()` gets its data from, you can pass in a `Source` parameter that tells it what to do:

```
.get(Source.CACHE)
```

or

```
.get(Source.SERVER)
```

Also see the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options) and [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)) for `get(Source)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Firestore Settings (this is in Kotlin)

```
val firestoreSettings: FirebaseFirestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                        .setPersistenceEnabled(false/*OR True | Control it whenever you need*/)
                        .setSslEnabled(true)
                        .build()
firebaseFirestore.firestoreSettings = firestoreSettings
```

Comment: why the persistence is set to false ? could you please give a little bit explanation ? because I want to use cached documents that previously fetched from server

Comment: you said "let say my app will ALWAYS be online." so it force to be online. control and limit it on you app opening or resuming...